# more condition in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

I want to auto calculate 
if Column F has word K and L - G > M and need more than 0.5 then value in E is same value But if L - G more than M but not more than 0.25 then value in E will / 2 and Value in J = "0.5"

Just now i can only do in the top table but it to be like bottom table.
The bottom table is the value after i tell above.

What should i add more in IF

Here is my code

```
Sub calcu()

Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim d As Integer
Dim t1 As String
Dim t2 As String

Dim hdp As Double
Dim ts1 As Double
Dim ts2 As Double
Dim g1 As Double
Dim g2 As Double
Dim g3 As Double
Dim g4 As Double


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

a = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For b = 1 To a
If IsNumeric(Cells(b, "C").Value) Then
hdp = Cells(b, "G").Value

ts1 = Cells(b, "L")
ts2 = Cells(b, "M")
t1 = Cells(b, "F")
t2 = Cells(b, "H")
g1 = ts1 - hdp
g2 = ts2 - hdp
g3 = ts2 + hdp
g4 = ts1 + hdp

If InStr(t1, "K") And ts1 - g3 = 0.25 Then
Cells(b, "E") = ((Cells(b, "E") - 1) / 2) + 1
Cells(b, "J") = 0.5

ElseIf InStr(t2, "K") And ts2 - g4 = 0.25 Then
Cells(b, "J") = ((Cells(b, "J") - 1) / 2) + 1
Cells(b, "E") = 0.5

ElseIf InStr(t1, "K") And ts1 - ts2 = 0 And InStr(hdp, "0.25") Then
Cells(b, "J") = ((Cells(b, "J") - 1) / 2) + 1
Cells(b, "E") = 0.5

ElseIf InStr(t2, "K") And ts1 - ts2 = 0 And InStr(hdp, "0.25") Then
Cells(b, "E") = ((Cells(b, "E") - 1) / 2) + 1
Cells(b, "J") = 0.5

ElseIf InStr(t1, "K") And ts1 - ts2 = 1 And InStr(hdp, "1.25") Then
Cells(b, "J") = ((Cells(b, "J") - 1) / 2) + 1
Cells(b, "E") = 0.5

ElseIf InStr(t2, "K") And ts2 - ts1 = 1 And InStr(hdp, "1.25") Then
Cells(b, "E") = ((Cells(b, "E") - 1) / 2) + 1
Cells(b, "J") = 0.5

ElseIf InStr(t1, "K") And ts1 - ts2 = 2 And InStr(hdp, "2.25") Then
Cells(b, "J") = ((Cells(b, "J") - 1) / 2) + 1
Cells(b, "E") = 0.5

ElseIf InStr(t2, "K") And ts2 - ts1 = 2 And InStr(hdp, "2.25") Then
Cells(b, "E") = ((Cells(b, "E") - 1) / 2) + 1
Cells(b, "J") = 0.5

ElseIf InStr(t1, "K") And ts1 - ts2 = 3 And InStr(hdp, "3.25") Then
Cells(b, "J") = ((Cells(b, "J") - 1) / 2) + 1
Cells(b, "E") = 0.5

ElseIf InStr(t2, "K") And ts2 - ts1 = 3 And InStr(hdp, "3.25") Then
Cells(b, "E") = ((Cells(b, "E") - 1) / 2) + 1
Cells(b, "J") = 0.5

ElseIf InStr(t1, "K") And g1 > ts2 Then
Cells(b, "J") = "0"



ElseIf InStr(t1, "K") And g1 < ts2 Then
Cells(b, "E") = "0"


ElseIf InStr(t1, "K") And g1 = ts2 Then
Cells(b, "J") = 1
Cells(b, "E") = 1

ElseIf InStr(t2, "K") And g2 > ts1 Then
Cells(b, "E") = "0"

ElseIf InStr(t2, "K") And g2 < ts1 Then
Cells(b, "J") = "0"

ElseIf InStr(t2, "K") And g2 = ts1 Then
Cells(b, "E") = 1
Cells(b, "J") = 1

Else
Cells(b, "E") = "error"
Cells(b, "J") = "error"

End If

End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub floats()


Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim d As Integer
Dim t1 As String
Dim t2 As String

Dim hdp As Double
Dim ts1 As Double
Dim ts2 As Double
Dim g1 As Double
Dim g2 As Double


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

a = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For b = 1 To a
If IsNumeric(Cells(b, "C").Value) Then
hdp = Cells(b, "G").Value

ts1 = Cells(b, "L")
ts2 = Cells(b, "M")
t1 = Cells(b, "F")
t2 = Cells(b, "H")
g1 = ts1 - hdp
g2 = ts2 - hdp
a1 = (ts1 - ts2)
a2 = (ts2 - ts1)

If InStr(t1, "K") And a1 = 0.25 Then
Cells(b, "E") = 0.5
Cells(b, "J") = Cells(b, "J") / 2


Else
Cells(b, "E") = "error"
Cells(b, "J") = "error"

End If

End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a great opportunity to re-structure your `If... Then` block to a `Select... Case` block.. It also looks like all of your if/then's could be booleans.

```
Select [ Case ] testexpression ' = boolean

    [ Case expressionlist ' where expressionlist = L-G > M or whatever. (True/False)
        [ statements ] ]

    [ Case Else
        [ elsestatements ] ]
End Select
```

Excel VBA offers decent case comprehension... go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx for info.

Comment: Can you help me on this ><

Comment: finally, i got this.

Comment: @NuttapongPhunsub feel free to follow-up with more questions if you need more help :)

Answer (score 0):

While I don't understand your conditions I'd highly recommend to rewrite the code a bit to make it easier for you to see what is going on:

```
Option Explicit

Sub calcu()

Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngRowNumber As Long

Dim t1 As String
Dim t2 As String

Dim hdp As Double
Dim ts1 As Double
Dim ts2 As Double
Dim g1 As Double
Dim g2 As Double


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For lngRowNumber = 1 To lngLastRow
    If IsNumeric(Cells(lngRowNumber, "C").Value) Then
        hdp = Cells(lngRowNumber, "G").Value

        ts1 = Cells(lngRowNumber, "L")
        ts2 = Cells(lngRowNumber, "M")
        t1 = Cells(lngRowNumber, "F")
        t2 = Cells(lngRowNumber, "H")
        g1 = ts1 - hdp
        g2 = ts2 - hdp


        If InStr(t1, "K") And g1 > ts2 Then
            Cells(b, "J") = "0"

        ElseIf InStr(t1, "K") And g1 < ts2 Then
            Cells(lngRowNumber, "E") = "0"

        ElseIf InStr(t1, "K") And g1 = ts2 Then
            Cells(lngRowNumber, "J") = 1
            Cells(lngRowNumber, "E") = 1

        ElseIf InStr(t2, "K") And g2 > ts1 Then
            Cells(lngRowNumber, "E") = "0"

        ElseIf InStr(t2, "K") And g2 < ts1 Then
            Cells(lngRowNumber, "J") = "0"

        ElseIf InStr(t2, "K") And g2 = ts1 Then
            Cells(lngRowNumber, "E") = 1
            Cells(lngRowNumber, "J") = 1

        Else
            Cells(lngRowNumber, "E") = "error"
            Cells(lngRowNumber, "J") = "error"

        End If
    End If
Next lngRowNumber

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

What I did is:
(1) Remove unnecessary variables
(2) Rename variables with meaningful names
(3) Indent the code so you can more easily see your conditions and the prerequisites that need to be met before it gets there.

The conditions you are trying to describe seem somewhat hazy and you might want to check if they truly all are mutually exclusive (only one of them can ever occur) as it is coded right now.

I know this is not the answer you've been looking for. But maybe it helps you figure out the solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you are after here, but you could try nested if statements. If nothing else it may help to clear up the code and help you work through the conditions that need to be satisfied.

```
If InStr(t1, "K") then 

    If g1 > ts2 Then
      Cells(b, "J") = "0"
    ElseIf g1 < ts2 Then
      Cells(b, "E") = "0"
    ElseIf g1 = ts2 Then
      Cells(b, "J") = 1
      Cells(b, "E") = 1
    End if

ElseIf InStr(t2, "K") Then

    If g2 > ts1 Then
        Cells(b, "E") = "0"
      ElseIf InStr(t2, "K") And g2 < ts1 Then
        Cells(b, "J") = "0"
      ElseIf InStr(t2, "K") And g2 = ts1 Then
        Cells(b, "E") = 1
        Cells(b, "J") = 1
    End if
Else
Cells(b, "E") = "error"
Cells(b, "J") = "error"

End If
```

I do recommend spending more time thinking about the conditions you are testing and the possible routes through that logic. I did not know how to incorporate the >0.5 or up to 0.25 parts of your request as I did not understand what was being asked.